# Problema con date en php y phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un problema para almacenar la hora en mi base de datos, tengo un formulario desde donde se envía una serie de datos pero por alguna razón la fecha no se inserta o solo quedan en ceros.

```
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Fecha y hora de Inicio:</label>
              <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-addon">
                  <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
                </div>
                <input type="date" id="fecha1" name="fecha1">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Fecha y hora de Término:</label>
              <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-addon">
                  <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
                </div>
                <input type="date" id="fecha2" name="fecha2">
              </div>
            </div>
```

Ahí están los inputs que tengo en el formulario ya que todo lo demas funciona correctamente.

function agregar() {

```
global $db, $_POST, $_FILES;

$uniqid = uniqid();
$filename = $uniqid . basename($_FILES["cupon_imagen"]["name"]);
$target_file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/admin-kupom/content/cupones/'. $filename;
$filename = 'http://www.kupomcity.com/admin-kupom/content/cupones/' . $filename;

$destacado = 0;
if ($_POST['destacado'] == 1) {
  $destacado = 1;
}

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["cupon_imagen"]["tmp_name"], $target_file))
{
  $sql = "INSERT INTO cupones (
    id_comercio,
    destacado,
    cantidad,
    image,
    titulo,
    texto,
    duracion,
    created_by,
    created_at,
    fecha_termino
  ) VALUES (
    :id_comercio,
    :destacado,
    :cantidad,
    :image,
    :titulo,
    :texto,
    :duracion,
    :id_usuario,
    :data1,
    :data2
  )";

  $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->bindParam(':id_comercio', $_POST['id_comercio'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $stmt->bindParam(':destacado', $destacado, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindParam(':data1', $_POST['fecha1'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindParam(':data2', $_POST['fecha2'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindParam(':cantidad', $_POST['cantidad'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindParam(':image', $filename, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindParam(':titulo', $_POST['titulo'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindParam(':texto', $_POST['texto'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindParam(':duracion', $_POST['duracion'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindParam(':id_usuario', $_SESSION['user']['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $stmt->execute();
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

}

Aquí esta mi función para insertar la información a la base de datos, no se que esta mal o que me falta para que me inserte las fechas en la base de datos.
Los campos son del tipo date en mi tabla de base de datos.

Comment: Seguramente es porque los formatos de fecha son diferentes, cuál es el del input y cuál el de la base de datos? Tienesn que ser iguales

Comment: el input tiene formato dia-mes-año mientras que la BD tiene formato año-mes-dia.

Comment: Pues sólo tienes que poner el formato igual al de la base de datos antes de insertar, por ejemplo con date. Si es datetime en base de datos tienes que añadir hh:mm:ss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Muy buenas estimado. Si quiere poner para el formulario, solo tendrías que añadir esto para PHP, lo que hace para el form, como veo que es datetime:

```
<input type="text" name="fecha" value="<?php date_default_timezone_set('America/Santiago'); echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');?>"><br>
```

`date_default_timezone_set('America/Santiago')` se puede cambiar por el país correspondiente, digamos 'Europe/Berlin' de alemania, capital: berlín.

Dejo este link para que puedas comprender [Listado de zonas horarias admitidas](http://php.net/manual/es/timezones.php)

Espero que te haya ayudado! Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto:

```
$nuevafecha = date( "Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime(str_replace("(Hora de verano romance)", "", $fecha)));
```

La hora que coge el input date está en este formato:

**Sun Jul 02 2017 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (Hora de verano romance)**

Con la función de arriba la convertimos en formato Date para la base de datos.

Comment: Lo probare a ver que tal va con eso.